# Flutter when displaying text via the text widget, sometimes the text is displayed into two lines

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout

i'am trying to display a text using a text widget in flutter, but i'am having an issue with the final result the text breaks into two line event somme space is available...
thank for your help ...[you can find a screenshot from my emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNeuF.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the maximum number of lines on a text widget by passing the `maxLines` parameter.

```
Text(_someLongText, maxLines: 1);
```

which of course means the text will cut off before it goes to a next line:

without maxlines:

```
+-------------+
| some text   |
| long text   |
+-------------+
```

with maxlines: 1

```
+-------------+
| some text lo|
+-------------+
```

You can define the behaviour of the overflow text with the overflow parameter:

```
Column(children: [
  Text('this si some long text', maxLines: 1, overflow: TextOverflow.clip),
  Text('this si some long text', maxLines: 1, overflow: TextOverflow.elipsis),
  Text('this si some long text', maxLines: 1, overflow: TextOverflow.fade),
  Text('this si some long text', maxLines: 1, overflow: TextOverflow.visible),
]);
```

will make:

```
+-------------+
| this is some|
+-------------+
+-------------+
| this is s...|
+-------------+
+-------------+
| this is some| // can't do this one but the text fades away
+-------------+
+-------------+
| this is some long text
+-------------+
```

Hopefully you can fix the issue with that.

Comment: h8moss, Thank you for your response did checked the screen shot? The problem occurs when displaying special characters example: when displaying 'test test test test test' no problem but when the string contain a special character like - $& the widget display the text on two line....

Comment: @LazyCoder00 I see, so you don't have a problem when displaying alphanumeric characters? Could you show some code so we can try to replicate the issue?

Comment: thank you for your time, you can reproduce the issue by simply displaying this String with the text widget like this:
Text(
                  "c~1{rQr/bCMrLQXw*n£JJ7Ffdw0kSc5v<9xgEnrm'=Nn2okf£",
                  maxLines: 3,
                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                )

Comment: Ok, so the issue has to do with the fact that the line break is introduced after the `/` character instead of at the end of the text widget correct?

Comment: if so, I believe the `softWrap` option will fix the issue: `Text( "c~1{rQr/bCMrLQXw*n£JJ7Ffdw0kSc5v<9xgEnrm'=Nn2okf£", maxLines: 3, overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis, softWrap: false)`, please test this bit of code and tell me if it fixes the problem?

Comment: I will test it and let you know, thank you so much

Comment: it worked with softwrap:false, i added a scrollbar the display the rest of the line, thank you  this is expected result i want

Comment: Very happy to have helped you